# Convert Json objects to single array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[image]

this is what i am looking for

```
          markers: marker[] = [
        {
      lat: 18.533989,
      lng: 73.825592,

     },
      {
        lat: 18.540474,
       lng: 73.837510,
         label: 'B',
      },
       {
         lat: 18.540972,
        lng: 73.832146,
       label: 'C'
       }
     ]

 }
```

this is what i have tried

```
for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        // Iterate over numeric indexes from 0 to 5, as everyone expects.
        let newobj = res[i].destinationAddress.location.coordinates;
        console.log(newobj);
        for(let j = 0; j < res.length; j ++){
          this.markersArr.push(newobj[j]);
        }
```

i am using angular 6 i need to convert json obj into array

Comment: this is not java

Comment: You should start by creating the object `{lat, lng}` that you want to push in the array.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific of what the input is? You say they are different arrays, but then you seem to be iterating over one.

Comment: you can use new ES2018 object spread over operator (...spread) and combine your arrays

Answer (score 1):

Try this code inside you inner loop.

```
const [lat, lng] = newobj[j];
this.markersArr.push({
  lat : lat,
  lng : lng,
  label : 'C' // or whatever value you want to add
})
```